simplifying an integral involving product of modified Bessel function of first kind, exponential and powers of the argument
I am trying to evaluate the following integral:
\begin{equation}
\int_{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}^\infty u^{m+1} (u^2-\varepsilon)^{\frac k4-\frac12} \exp{\left(-\frac{u^2}{2\varsigma}\right)}I_{\frac k2-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{u^2-\varepsilon}\zeta}\right)  du
\end{equation}
where $m,k$ are positive integers, and $\varepsilon,\varsigma >0$.
Now, I can write
\begin{equation*}
I_{\frac k2-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{u^2-\varepsilon}\varsigma}\right) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(u^2-\varepsilon)^{j+\frac k4 -\frac12}}{(2\varsigma)^{2j+\frac k2} j!\Gamma(\frac k2+j+1)}
\end{equation*}
So, then, the integral is an infinite series involving $j$ of
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}^{\infty } u^{m+1} \left(u^2-\varepsilon\right)^{j+\frac{k}{2}-1} \exp \left(-\frac{u^2}{2 \varsigma}\right) du
\end{equation*}
Now, I think I can show the following:
\begin{equation}
\int_{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}^{\infty } u^{m+1} \left(u^2-\varepsilon\right)^{j+\frac{k}{2}-1} \exp \left(-\frac{u^2}{2 \varsigma}\right)\, du=\quad\frac12{\varsigma^{\frac{1}{2} (2 j+k+m)}} \Bigg(\frac{\Gamma \left(j+\frac{k}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(-j-\frac{k}{2}-\frac{m}{2}\right) \left(\frac{\varepsilon}{\varsigma}\right)^{\frac{1}{2} (2 j+k+m)}}{2\Gamma \left(-\frac{m}{2}\right)} {}_1F_1\left(\frac{m+2}{2};\frac{1}{2} (2 j+k+m+2);-\frac{\varepsilon}{2 \varsigma}\right)+2^{\frac{1}{2} (2 j+k+m)} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2} (2 j+k+m)\right) \, _1F_1\left(-j-\frac{k}{2}+1;-j-\frac{k}{2}-\frac{m}{2}+1;-\frac{\varepsilon}{2 \varsigma}\right)\Bigg)
\end{equation}
So, I get the original integral to be an infinite series in $j$ of terms involving $\Gamma(\cdot)$ and ${}_1F_1(\cdot)$ functions.
I was wondering if there is a more simplified, elegant expression, perhaps more directly obtained, than the above. Thanks a lot for any help and suggestions!

The integral almost looks like the Marcum Q or less common Nuttal Q functions.

Thanks for this, I have heard of Marcum Q, but never previously of the Nuttal Q. I will also look into whether there are algorithms to calculate these functions. Thanks again, @TymaGaidash
